# Rspec with a Factory and a virtual attribute from a model does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

i'm using Rspec and factory girl to set my tests. I have a user factory and then i'm testing with rspec.

In a module named GameEngine::Formulas, i have a virtual attribute(actually hp is already i the model, it's overridden here) :

```
def hp
    ((self[:hp] * 5) * (self.level + 1)) if self.first_class == 'Fighter'
    ((self[:hp] * 4) * (self.level + 1)) if self.first_class == 'Ranger'
    ((self[:hp] * 2) * (self.level + 1)) if self.first_class == 'Magician'
end
```

When i remove this virtual attrib, the test works fine. But if i leave it here, i get that :

```
 Failure/Error: let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Hp can't be blank
```

FACTORY :

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
    f.sequence(:username) { |n| "test#{n}" }
    f.password "1234567890"
    f.sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@test.com" }
    f.first_class 'Ranger'
    f.hp 10000
    f.strength 100
    f.magic 100
    f.dexterity 100
    f.accuracy 10
    f.armor 20
    f.level 1
end
```

Why is that ?

Comment: What does your factory look like?

Comment: I added the factory. I actually resolved that by changing the ifs structure thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the original code is that it returns `nil` except when `first_class == 'Magician'`. A statement with a trailing conditional returns nil if the condition is false, e.g.

```
> 1 + 1 if true
# => 2

> 1 + 1 if false
# => nil
```

All three tests are performed for each invocation, so the results of the first two are masked by the subsequent one(s).

You could rewrite it with a case statement:

```
  def hp
    case first_class
    when 'Fighter'
      ((self[:hp] * 5) * (level + 1))
    when 'Ranger'
      ((self[:hp] * 4) * (level + 1))
    when 'Magician'
      ((self[:hp] * 2) * (level + 1))
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this by changing the if structure to if..elsif.

I guess that explicitly returning the value and then having another if check was messing the things. Not sure exactly why this is the case, but it worked when i did that.